# Ubuntu network profiles across machines?

Tags: server, user-profile

I have multiple Linux machines at home, operated by different people. What I'd like is for someone to be able to **log on to any of the different machines and have the same settings**, including their "home" folder, available to them. Much like how I can log on to my account at work on any computer, even remotely, and access my profile.

This [isn't the same as a shared home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859301/how-to-organise-a-shared-home-directory), because I want a single account per person across many machines, not a single home folder across many accounts.

It might [be similar to making a home server using Ubuntu desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop?rq=1), but from that post I can't tell if it will allow single accounts managed centrally?

It's [probably much like this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61397/can-i-have-a-single-login-for-multiple-machines), but that's both dated (over six years old) and based on using a Windows server.

The [setup is described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727504/what-is-it-called-when-you-can-log-into-multiple-workstations-with-one-username), I think, but that post doesn't contain a description of what's required.

Is this feasible with Ubuntu? (Added complication, I've migrated most of the computers to Linux Mint from Ubuntu, but assume that it's still close enough to Ubuntu that it isn't an issue).